# Primary Key At the End of Foreign Key index in MySQL is in order for sure?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.7

I am aware that any Index in MySQL Innodb contains primary key value in the end of it. If there was a table as follows.

```sql
create table BaseTbl ( 
    base_id int not null primary key auto_increment, 
    base_name varchar(30) 
);

create table Tbl (
    record_id int not null primary key auto_increment,
    base_id int not null,
    foreign key (base_id) references BaseTbl(base_id)
);
```

Table `Tbl` would have an index on `base_id` because that is FK. And that would implicitly have `record_id` as the final key part. Would that be ordered?

Example:

If the data was

```
BaseTbl
+---------+-----------+
| base_id | base_name |
+---------+-----------+
|       1 | Name1     |
|       2 | Name2     |
|       3 | Name3     |
+---------+-----------+

Tbl
+-----------+---------+
| record_id | base_id |
+-----------+---------+
|         1 |       1 |
|         2 |       2 |
|         3 |       1 |
|         4 |       1 |
|         5 |       1 |
|         6 |       2 |
|         7 |       2 |
|         8 |       1 |
|         9 |       3 |
|        10 |       1 |
|        11 |       2 |
|        12 |       3 |
+-----------+---------+
```

Would the `base_id` FK index's `record_id` part will it be ordered? Like this?

```sql
+---------+-----------+
| base_id | record_id |
+---------+-----------+
|       1 |         1 |
|       1 |         2 |
|       1 |         3 |
|       1 |         4 |
|       1 |         5 |
|       2 |         6 |
|       2 |         7 |
|       2 |         8 |
|       3 |         9 |
|       3 |        10 |
|       3 |        11 |
|       3 |        12 |
|       3 |        13 |
|       3 |        14 |
|       3 |        15 |
+---------+-----------+
```

It seems like it is ordered, as I did not see 'using FileSort' when I explicitly tried mentioning `Order By` on `record_id`. But I'd like a confirmation or point in documentation that confirms this. (I failed to find it myself).

Comment: Any index contains primary key expression. Index entries are sorted. There is no INCLUDE clause for indexes in MySQL. I think that sorting procedure sorts whole entries and do not distinguishes where is index expression part and where is attached primary key expression part. See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=765d3d108b1a62f362017273b2d5ba97) - records ordered by index by common field are secondary sorted by primary key.

Comment: PS. The common (non-primary) index and the index created for foreign key reference support differs in nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FK is a constraint.  To facilitate checking that constraint, an `INDEX` is created.  Run `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for confirmation.  An InnoDB `INDEX` is expanded to include PK column(s).  Also, if there is an index with the *leftmost* column(s) matching the FK's column(s), the FK is happy.

When doing a `SELECT`, the Optimizer has many possible ways to do the query.  If you do not have an `ORDER BY`, then you must not assume the output is in any particular order.  The Optimizer may not have chosen the index you expect, or there could be a `GROUP BY` that is performed by first sorting, or the `GROUP BY` is done by hashing, hence randomly ordered.  Etc.

"Filesort" is a misnomer in two ways.  It may not involve a "file"; that is it might be done in RAM.  And it may need to be plural -- For example, `GROUP BY a ORDER BY b` is likely to involve *two* sorts.  `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON ...` is clearer on this than a plain `EXPLAIN`.

So, yes, the index for the FK is effectively as you describe (2 columns, ordered).  But so what?  Don't trust it; tack on an `ORDER BY` if you need the ordering.  As I mentioned above, the Optimizer is free to ignore that index.

A tip:  If you want to make use of both columns of the 'index' in question, then explicitly specify `INDEX(base_id, record_id)`.  The FK should see that and say "That index is all I need; I won't make another one".  Humans reading your code will say "Hmmmm, the schema designer needs these two columns indexed for some reason".